# Complex equation removing i from logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis

$z = -i \ln (i(2 \pm \sqrt(3))$

The book has the answer

$z = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n - i \log_e (2 \pm \sqrt{3})$

I am confused about this answer, because when I try to take the modulus of the argument of $\ln$ I get the following: $\sqrt{i^2(2 \pm \sqrt{3})^2} = i(2 \pm \sqrt{3})$ (aka I get $z = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n - i \log_e (i(2 \pm \sqrt{3}))$)

But in the books answer, it just discards the i.

What happened?

Comment: How do you end up with a purely imaginary complex modulus? $|z|=\sqrt{\Re(z)^2+\Im(z)^2}$. For $\log(i(2\pm\sqrt{3}))$, convert the argument $z=i(2\pm\sqrt{3})$ to the polar form $|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$ and use $\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$ by definition of logarithm. Your answer may also be not correct not necessarily only because of some $\log$ and $i$ trickery, so posting the original problem might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you think to get $\sqrt{i^2(2\pm\sqrt{3})^2}$? The formula $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ does not have any $i$.

The modulus is $|i(2\pm\sqrt{3})|=|i|\cdot|(2\pm\sqrt{3})|=1\cdot (2\pm\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: (-1): this does not answer the question.

Comment: @dbanet It does answer the question what happened with the $i$ in the book. The rest of the calculation in OP is correct.